# Correct Syntax to Include object data in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a jquery selector as per the below code. However, my js is pretty poor and i'm not sure what the correct syntax is to use data.key as the value here (data.key should have a numeric value btw). I'd know how to do this in php! But not sure here :(

```
onClick: function(data) {
    if($(".myForm select option[value=data.key]").is(':selected')){
        alert('foo');
    }
}
```

Any advice would be very gratefully received!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a string. Use the `+` operator.

```
".myForm select option[value=" + data.key + "]")
```

Comment: It's advisable to at least quote the value.

Comment: Ahhh, that's the one. You beauty! Perfect!